# Link in Pdf not working : PhantomJs

Tags: pdf, hyperlink, phantomjs

I have converted my html page to pdf using phantomjs successfully. But there is a problem with it. the links to download a file in html are not working in pdf. i have done google also go thru the phantomjs portal and refrence but no help...

Any help is appreciated..
Thankyou

Answer (score 0):

Hyperlink actions in PhantomJs are [coming in 1.10 or 2.0](https://github.com/ariya/phantomjs/issues/10196). There's another solution that does not use PhantomJS [here](https://coderwall.com/p/aej2aq).